# How do I read variables from a remote server?

Tags: android, xml, string

I am currently working on a little remote image viewer app.

What I need to know is how to read string variables from a `Xml` file on a remote server and put them into a `String[]`. So my program can use them how I want. All the variable in the `Xml` file are strings (I.E "http://www.website.com/image.png")

I can do this with a local `Xml` but how would I do this from a remote `Xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use a SAX parser as described here http://www.codingforandroid.com/2010/12/reading-remote-xml-file-with-sax.html

Comment: I suggest using a sax parser also

Answer (score 0):

I just had to load XML for an app I am working on. This is the method I am currently using. You have to change it to suit your XML structure, but this should give you a pretty good idea. I am still new to java and android, so their may be a better solution

```
private void loadXML()
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db;
    try
    {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        try
        {
            Document doc = db.parse(new URL("http://yoursite.com/presentation.xml").openStream());
            Element docElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList nl = docElement.getElementsByTagName("Slide");

            if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0)
            {
                String slideArray[] = new String[nl.getLength()];
                vforumLength = nl.getLength();

                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
                {
                    Element slideElement = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    NodeList titleList   = slideElement.getElementsByTagName("Title");
                    Element titleElement = (Element) titleList.item(0);
                    String title         = titleElement.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    slideArray[i]        = title;
                    Log.i("xml",title);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vForum>
    <Slides>
        <Slide id="1" tcIn="00:00:00.0" tcOut="00:00:00.0">
            <Title>Title 1</Title>
        </Slide>
        <Slide id="2" tcIn="00:00:00.0" tcOut="00:00:00.0">
            <Title>Title 2</Title>
        </Slide>
        <Slide id="3" tcIn="00:00:00.0" tcOut="00:00:00.0">
            <Title>Title 3</Title>
        </Slide>
        <Slide id="4" tcIn="00:00:00.0" tcOut="00:00:00.0">
            <Title>Title 4</Title>
        </Slide>
        <Slide id="5" tcIn="00:00:00.0" tcOut="00:00:00.0">
            <Title>Title 5</Title>
        </Slide>
    </Slides>
</vForum>
```

my actual XML is a bit more complicated, but I trimmed it down so you dont have to go through the irrelevant data